# Delete parent and child records depending on search text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-delete, common-table-expression

Depending on a search text in my application I have to delete parent and child records from a table in the following format:

**`tabItem`**

```
+--------+--------------+----------+-----------------+
| ItemId | ItemParentId | ItemName | ItemDescription |
+--------+--------------+----------+-----------------+
```

If I type for example "information" in a textbox inside my application and click on "Filter", I have to remove every parent and child item if the lowest item in the tree contains "information".

Tree for better explanation:

```
Category 1
|
+--- Subcategory
     |
     +--- Subsubcategory
          |
          +--- Item (contains "information" in ItemDescription)
Category 2
|
+--- Subcategory
     |
     +--- Subsubcategory
          |
          +--- Item (doesn't contain "information")
```

Now I have to delete the item that contains "information" and all of it's parents and grandparents.

I tried it by using the following `cte`:

```
WITH cte_toDelete
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM tabItem
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte_toDelete.*
    FROM cte_toDelete
    INNER JOIN tabItem ON cte_toDelete.ItemParentId = tabItem.ItemId
)
DELETE FROM tabItem
WHERE ItemId IN
(
    SELECT ItemId
    FROM cte_toDelete
    WHERE cte_toDelete.ItemName NOT LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'
    AND cte_toDelete.ItemDescription NOT LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'
)
```

But when I run these lines, I get the following error:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

What is wrong with my `cte`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CTE allows The maximum 100 recursion only

we can change its setting by using `MAXRECURSION`, value for `MAXRECURSION` can be in between 0 to 32,767

for more info [MAXRECURSION](http://sqlhints.com/tag/the-statement-terminated-the-maximum-recursion-100-has-been-exhausted-before-statement-completion/)

```
WITH cte_toDelete
AS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM tabItem
   UNION ALL
   SELECT cte_toDelete.*
   FROM cte_toDelete
   INNER JOIN tabItem ON cte_toDelete.ItemParentId = tabItem.ItemId
)
DELETE FROM tabItem
WHERE ItemId IN
(
  SELECT ItemId
  FROM cte_toDelete
  WHERE cte_toDelete.ItemName NOT LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'
  AND cte_toDelete.ItemDescription NOT LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'
 )
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```